# parameter to return ndarray of objects in any numpy method?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I am working with very large numbers and need some special transforms from numpy.
For regular nd array creation, you can set dtype to object if you wish to use regular python types so you are not limited to numpy types.
But in the case of np.methods, which return an array like fft which process your original list fast Fourier transform and returns an array with the answer.
The problem being that, as you have no opportunity to decide which dtype the returned array is filled with, in the end for great numbers, there will be errors, unexpected roundings and so on. 
Is there no means to set a general parameter in numpy (like those that exist in pandas to set some printing parameters and so on), to decide to generate new arrays with such object types?

In the event it is not possible, how could I suggest Numpy team to add such convenient feature, and how could I derive/tweak its methods so I can handle the dtype in need to? Is there something doable with inheritance like properties (I am still not advanced enough in python to know the right lexicon about that, sorry)?
Thanks by advance

Comment: FFT (and many other numerical algorithms) is provided by C libraries, so it can't deal with Python number types.  There is no way to implement the feature you suggest.  Can you be more specific on the problem you are facing?  People will likely be able to help you with a specific problem.

Comment: By using `dtype=object` to store values like the Python long, you have essentially stepped outside of the scope of `numpy` functions.  You might as well use lists of those numbers.  Fast `numpy` calculations make use of compiled code, usually working with `c` floats, doubles, and occasionally the `longdouble` mentioned in the `extended` doc.  `fft` uses `fftpack` (either in Fortran or C source).

Comment: Thanks. Well I guess I am stuck then, since I need those functions (I am using big number for algorithms trying to predict primes and so on), and at the same time need the object. for handling the big numbers. As long as the function would be implemented, I could care less about processing speed for this matter (well, not exactly, but that's not my primary goal... Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe the `lisp` family of languages builds on extended precision numbers.

Comment: @AndoJurai You might also want to take a look at PARI/GP.  Again, if you state your problem more explicitely, chances are people will be able to help you.  You basically asked about an attempted solution (using Numpy for something it can't be used for) without stating what you actually want to do.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: As answered in my comment, I can't be more specific than that. Not because I don't want to, but because my given task is to use FFT to transform lists of numbers, then feed it to another program which is more or less completed by my teammates. I have built the list generation thing from zero, then have to FFT them. But can't with numpy, from what you say. I thus have to implement this by myself;) Thanks for the PARI/GP pointer, I am gonna look into it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I guess that Pari won't fit either, since it is based upon C. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: If it's just about running an FFT on a Python list, and you don't care too much about performance, you can simply implement the FFT yourself in pure Python.  It's just a couple of lines of code. (See e.g. ￼https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Python)

Comment: Well, you would have to use [some arbitrary-precision floating-point library](http://mpmath.org/doc/0.19/index.html) as well, since Python's `exp()` will always return a double-precision number, and I understand that's not enough for your use case.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, that looks good